# Why Unity draws ray in wrong direction when given origin coordinates and destination coordinates?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

[image: Image of ray and camera position]
[image: Changing of the angle between Main char and the raycase]
I am making a game and I am writing a script that will prevent camera from passing through walls. The (white) ray is checking for collisions. It should go from Main character to the camera, yet it goes in another direction, completely different from the one that was given. Also, when I move my Main Character the angle of the ray also moves.

I've tried to change my destination coordinates to be like :

```
gameObject.transform.position + New Vector3(...);
```

However, the result was similar.

```
bool HasHit()
    {
//check if ray hits a collider
         return (Physics.Raycast(gameObject.transform.position, TestForHit.transform.position, out hit));
    }
 void DrawLines()
    {
//debug the ray (hits wrong collider)
        Debug.DrawRay(gameObject.transform.position, TestForHit.transform.position);
    }
```

I expect that the ray checks for colliders only between Main Character and Camera, like straight line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using [`Debug.DrawLine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawLine.html) since you're using a start location and a *destination*.

---

Note: The [`Debug.DrawRay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawRay.html) function uses a start location and a *direction* as its first two parameters and cannot specify a length (it'll go forever). If you have two locations, `A` and `B` and want to draw a ray between them, you need to get the *direction* to draw the ray:

```
Vector3 A;
Vector3 B;
Vector3 direction = (B - A).normalized;
Debug.DrawRay(A, direction);
```

The same goes for [`Physics.RayCast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html).  You are using a *destination* as the second parameter when you should be using a *direction*.

Comment: Okay, I agree about the DrawLine function has start and end. However, the ray checks in wrong direction for collision. I am looking for a solution about why is it happening? On the first picture the angle between Main Character and the ray is like  30-45 degrees, while on the second picture is almost 90 degrees.

Comment: `Physics.Raycast` is supposed to use a _direction_ instead of a _destination_.  You're using a _destination_ in your example code.  Your _direction_ will be equal to `(TestForHit.transform.position - gameObject.transform.position).normalized`